# Escape special characters in FFmpeg subtitle filename

Tags: ffmpeg, escaping

If your subtitle file name is "Hi, y'all.srt", how do you escape this properly for FFmpeg? The comma works escaped with backslash, but I can't get the quote to work no matter what tricks I try!

```
$ ffmpeg -vf subtitles="Hi\, y\\\'all.srt" -t 1 -f null -

ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fba7af36080] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.7 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 1.4.8 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fba7af36080] Unable to open Hi, yall.srt
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fba7ad05d60] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args 'Hi, y\all.srt'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: No such file or directory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've got for Bash.

```
$ ls                                                                                                                                                               
'file [with] spaces : colons : , commas, %percents%, '\'' single and "double"'\'' quotes, and \ backslashes\.mp4'
```

with which the following invocation will work:

```
i=$(ls)
e=${i//\\/\\\\\\\\} # escape backslashes
e=${e//:/\\\\:}     # escape : (used to pass params to filter)
e=${e//,/\\,}       # escape , (used to separate filters)
e=${e//;/\\;}       # escape ; (used to separate filterchains)
e=${e//\'/\\\\\\\'} # escape ' (parsed by filter)
e=${e//\[/\\[}      # escape [ (used to name components of filtergraph)
e=${e//\]/\\]}      # escape ] (same as above)

ffmpeg -i "${i}" -vf "subtitles=${e}:si=8" "out.mp4"
```

The input filename was

```
file [with] spaces : colons : , commas, %percents%, ' single and "double"' quotes, and \ backslashes\.mp4
```

and the final escaped string looks like

```
file \[with\] spaces \\: colons \\: \, commas\, %percents%\, \\\' single and "double"\\\' quotes\, and \\\\ backslashes\\\\.mp4
```

This seems to be all of the (printable) special characters, as a file with name

```
!@#$%^&*()-_+=[]{}\|;:,.<>?`~'
.mp4
```

(with the literal newline) works for this invocation.

Note that if you want to escape for drawtext, you need to double the number of backslashes (`e=${i//\\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\}`) and add an escape for `%`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7, this works:

```
subtitles="Hi\, y\\\'all.srt"
```

Comment: Doesn't work on macOS with 1-4 backslashes. I tried all other thinkable variants like `'subtitles=a\,'"\'"'b.srt'`, which changes the error message slightly: `Unable to open a,b.srt` and `Error initialising filter subtitles with args 'a,'b.srt'`. (Notice the missing quote in the first error message.) So this seems like a bug to me. What do you think?

Comment: Try , but without enclosing the filter string in quotes, like in my answer. You're on MacOS so bash, I presume.

Comment: It looks like some of your answer is missing. Anyway, I tried without surrounding quotes. Doesn't work for any number of backslashes.

Comment: Can you share the full log of this command : `ffmpeg -vf subtitles="Hi\, y\\\'all.srt" -t 1 -f null -`?

Comment: See update. The filename is misprinted even in the error messages.

Comment: `-vf subtitles='Hi\, y'\''all.srt'` ?

Comment: I know I am late to the party, but have run into this same exact issue, specifically using a full path to a subtitle file - seems to be a Windows only issue, with parsing escaped characters.  Even if you follow this old thread: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3334 it will not work.  The only solution I found was using a file without special characters local to your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I wanted to post an answer here because I came across a similar issue and figured out a way around it. This was tested in Windows 8.1.

**The workaround is to create a symlink to your file first with a name that ffmpeg likes, and use that instead.**

eg.

```
mklink input.mkv "my file with [strange] characters.mkv"
```

Then you can use it with ffmpeg like so:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf subtitles=input.mkv -y output.mp4
```

This works for .srt files as well.

---

There seems to be a bug with ffmpeg where if you're using a file in the subtitles filter that has special characters in it, ffmpeg won't find the file. I had a collection of files I wanted to burn subtitles in but they all had special characters (square brackets) in the filename. I could rename all of my files, and remove the special characters, but that seemed like a pain to do and I'd rather find a way that doesn't care about how the source file is named. The best workaround I could find is to just create a symlink to the file itself and have ffmpeg call on the symlink. If I'm iterating over many files, all I would need to do is change the symlink to the next file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file named subtitle's.srt in a D:\Videos folder you can escape it like this `"subtitles='D\:\\Videos\\subtitle'\\\''s.srt'"`.

Example:

```
ffmpeg.exe -in file.mkv -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -vf "subtitles='D\:\\Videos\\subtitle'\\\''s.srt':si=0" file.mp4
```

This was tested on Windows 10.